# What order are the programming languages derived in?

Tags: programming-languages, language-history

For instance, I know that basically all languages that are object oriented based are basically derivatives of C# or C++ correct? Does anyone know the order they came in? Like C -> C++ -> C# -> PHP, etc.

Comment: I would be hard-pressed to call Delphi a derivative of either C++ or C#, considering that Delphi inspired C# in the first place.

Comment: PHP definitely isn't after C#.

Comment: Every single word of this question is factually incorrect....

Comment: It is easy to get this kind of impression if you don't sit down and read some history. Computer Science is more than 50 years old now, and things have been happening *fast* the whole time, there is more stuff now fading into the misty depths of time then is currently in vogue. Best not to assume that you know things. Object oriented language derive their inspiration at some level from Simula and Smalltalk.

Comment: I like how a language that first appeared in 1995 is supposed to have derived from one that first appeared in 2001. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might cover it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages

Comment: Never actually knew how many programming languages were out there.

Comment: Peruse http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net for more!

Answer (score 9):

I know my ancient history, not my recent history.

Procedural languages are rooted in FORTRAN, the first language to compile arbitrarily complicated high-level formulas to machine code.  FORmula TRANslator (John Backus, Turing award).

Procedural languages may have reached their apogee with Algol-60 (committee).

Important derivatives of Algol-60 include Simula-67 and Pascal, and via Pascal, the Ada, Modula, and Oberon families.  Perhaps CLU was influenced also.

**All object-oriented languages have roots in Simula-67**, which was an Algol derivative (Nygaard and Dahl, Turing award winners).

Smalltalk-80 and C with classes (became C++) were both directly influenced by Simula-67.  I don't know if Objective-C was influenced directly from Simula or indirectly from Smalltalk.  Likewise Delphi.  Self and Ruby both have strong Smalltalk heritage.  Java has strong Simula/C++ heritage; C# has strong Java heritage.

Functional languages are rooted in LISP, for LISt Processor (John McCarthy, Turing award winner).  Functional languages were also strongly influenced by John Backus's Turing lecture, in which he asked if programming could escape the von Neumann model of programming with mutation, one word at a time.  A great flowering occurred, including APL, ISWIM, Hope, ML, and Miranda.  Then later, Clean, Haskell, Objective Caml.  Still  later, Clojure, Scala, and F#.

Then we have the niche players:

- String-processing languages like SNOBOL and Icon
- Languages based on substitution, like TRAC, sh, TeX, Tcl, and PHP
- Dynamic postfix languages like FORTH and PostScript
- Logic languages like Prolog and Mercury

I won't go on.

Comment: +1, That's a good introduction to the history.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a history in graphical format: http://www.levenez.com/lang/

Comment: dang thats a crazy chart. that must have sucked to put that together.

Comment: @chadley: That's why tools like Graphviz exist.